# How do I convert px to mm?

Tags: codenameone

My app is a mobile phone app for iOS and Android.

My UI designer will provide Figma files for my app.
The padding, margin, and font size will be represented as px.
How do I convert to mm for the theme in cn1 per the advice in [use_millimeters developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_use_millimeters_for_paddingmargin_and_font_sizes)?

What is the best screen width in px as the standard for iOS and Android in the Figma design?

Comment: The whole POINT of using mm is that you don't worry about this.  The size will be different on different devices.  That's because there IS no standard.  If you figure an average phone at 400dpi, that's about 15px/mm.

Comment: The size of padding, margin, and font size should be represented as mm as recommended in cn1 developer guide. How do I convert Figma's px design to cn1 theme mm design? Should I determine the screen size in px for Figma's design, dpi of a standard phone? Then I can calculate the padding, margin, and font size in mm for cn1 theme setting.

Comment: Find a screen where your design looks good, find its DPI, and do the math yourself.  There is no rule here.

Comment: Yep. Tim is right here. Design for a high resolution device and then use that as the basis for conversion.